# Spring Data Rest JPA - Can't lazy load OneToMany bidirectional relationship

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have two entities, Company and Job, with an OneToMany bidirectional relationship. My problem is that i can't lazy load the Company's `List<Job> jobs`.

For example when i do:

GET `/api/companies/1` this is the JSON response:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "foo",
  ...
  "_embedded": {
    "jobs": [
      {...},
       ...
      {...}
    ],
    "employees": [
      {...},
      {...}
    ]
  },
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/companies/1"
    },
    "jobs": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/companies/1/jobs"
    },
    "employees": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/companies/1/employees"
    }
  }
}
```

I don't want to have the `_embedded` since i didn't set the FetchType=EAGER.
Here are my models:

**Company.java**

```
@Entity
public class Company {

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Job> jobs;

    ...

    public Company() {
    }

    ...

}
```

**Job.java**

```
@Entity
public class Job {

    @Column(nullable = false)
    public String title;

    @Column(length = 10000)
    public String description;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Company company;

    ...

    public Job() {
    }

    ...

}
```

As you can see the same thing happens for other OneToMany relationships (employees). Can i avoid returning the whole list of job openings or employees every time?

EDIT: from the Job side the lazy load works fine! I don't get in the response the company that is related with a Job. I have to explicitly do `/api/jobs/123/company` in order to get the company.

EDIT2: Projections only work for collections. In this case it's not what i need. Excerpts could work, but i want to avoid them. I don't want to explicilty do `/api/companies/1?projection=MyProjection` since i won't use more than one. I want to change the default behavior, just like the projections do in collections.

EDIT3: i tried this

```
@RestResource(exported = false)
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "company")
private List<Job> jobs;
```

and i get the error `Detected multiple association links with same relation type! Disambiguate association`.

**it's really annoying. I just need to get rid of `_embedded`. Anything?**

Comment: This is not really a question about JPA, it's a question about whether the collections within `Company` should be serialized.  It would be the same problem if the relationship were just POJOs not mapped to persistent objects.

Comment: In this case a `@RestResource(exported = false)` or `@JsonIgnore` on the `jobs` field should suffice (see [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.hiding-repositories)).

Comment: @DavidRiccitelli but i need them to be exported. I just need to lazy load them, so i will get a company's jobs only when i do `/api/companies/1/jobs`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Entity Graph.Entity graphs are used to override at runtime the fetch settings of attribute mappings.For example

```
@Repository
public interface GroupRepository extends CrudRepository<GroupInfo, String> {

  @EntityGraph(attributePaths = { "members" })
  GroupInfo getByGroupName(String name);

}
```

From Spring Data Jpa Documentation "4.3.10. Configuring Fetch- and LoadGraphs"
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/

In addition;[image]